# Trying to extract subpart of a string conditionally into a new column

Tags: r, regex, substring

I am trying to extract only part of a string meeting particular criteria. I have a column composed of either 1, 2, or 3 values as a string containing one similar part, e.g.,

```
c( " apa1 ghg2 PA0134", "qrz3 PA2858", "PA5103", "gan3 jgr3 PA4301").
```

I would like to collect only `PAxxxx` values from the string, OR separate it into 3 columns but have one be only `PAxxxx` values.

I have tried using various incarnations of `gsub` separate or substring. But these all rely on consistent length or number of entries. Any start would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it using `regmatches` and `regexpr` in Base R:

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\bPA.+\\b", x))
# [1] "PA0134" "PA2858" "PA5103" "PA4301"
```

with `gregexpr`, we get a list:

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\bPA.+\\b", x))
# [[1]]
# [1] "PA0134"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "PA2858"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "PA5103"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "PA4301"
```

Or with `tidyr:extract` if we want a column:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(x) %>%
  extract(x, c("v1", "v2", "v3"), "\\b(\\w*)\\s?(\\w*)\\s?(PA\\w+)\\b", remove = FALSE)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  x                v1    v2    v3    
  <chr>            <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 apa1 ghg2 PA0134 apa1  ghg2  PA0134
2 qrz3 PA2858      qrz3  ""    PA2858
3 PA5103           ""    ""    PA5103
4 gan3 jgr3 PA4301 gan3  jgr3  PA4301
```

**Data:**

```
x <- c("apa1 ghg2 PA0134", "qrz3 PA2858", "PA5103", "gan3 jgr3 PA4301")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `str_extract` from `stringr`.  Specify the word boundary (`\\b`), followed by the substring "PA" and one or more characters

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(v1, "\\bPA\\w+")
#[1] "PA0134" "PA2858" "PA5103" "PA4301"
```

---

If we want as a column, then we can split into two columns with `read.csv` from `base R`

```
read.csv(text = sub("\\b(PA)", ",\\1", v1), 
        header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#          V1     V2
#1 apa1 ghg2  PA0134
#2      qrz3  PA2858
#3            PA5103
#4 gan3 jgr3  PA4301
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("apa1 ghg2 PA0134", "qrz3 PA2858", "PA5103", "gan3 jgr3 PA4301")
```